# ¿donde ubicar un excel y como llamar al mismo desde android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, apache-poi

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Deseo leer un `Excel` y editar celdas para agregar valores usando `Apache POI`. Pero no sé en que carpeta de mi `aplicación android` se debe poner esos tipos de archivos. Y como obtener la ruta de ese archivo usando Apache POI.

Agradecería me puedan ayudar ya que soy nuevo en ello. Pero más que todo en que carpeta de mi proyecto debo agregar el archivo excel y como seria para llamarlo ya que para leer el archivo excel usando Apache POI ya he encontrado información suficiente.

Solo deseo saber en que carpeta debo ubicar el archivo y como obtener esa ruta.

Aquí le muestro las carpetas de mi proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar Apache POI library es una buena opción para leer archivos .xls, el archivo debes agregarlo como comentas dentro del directorio `/assets`:

```
/assets/myexcelfile.xls
```

para leerlo este es un ejemplo:

```
InputStream myInput;
// Inicializar asset manager
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
//  abrir archivo excel file name as myexcelfile.xls
myInput = assetManager.open("myexcelfile.xls");
// Crear un File System object POI
POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
// Crear un Workbook usando el File System
HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
// Obtener la primera hola del workbook
HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Tomado de :

[Cómo leer el archivo de Excel en el tutorial de Android: usando Apache POI lib, Asset Folder](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/how-to-read-excel-file-in-android-tutorial/)